# Nuget package "Not available in this source"... but VS still knows about it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget

I've come across a screen that I've never seen before, while playing with `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` source code, looking for a bug that's blocking my app from running properly.

As things stand right now, I can't even build the source code.

[image: screenshot]

I can't build this code, because the packages can't be found; yet, Visual Studio knows that the latest release is the one I want.  How is this possible? What (if anything) can I do to get the packages installed?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.1.0-preview1-final. On the official feeds, only the preview is available. You probably have somewhere a myget feed for the nightlies bound into the project

Comment: The nightlies are available under the aspnetcore-dev feed on myget: https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Probably the order of the feeds is wrong (either in your VS NuGet settings or the projects Nuget.Config.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there was a separate feed for them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Nuget package “Not available in this source”… but VS still knows about it?

You should select `nuget.org` as package source, not `All`. Tseng pointed the correct direction. You probably have a myget feed in your project/Visual Studio.

According to the package [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.1.0-preview1-final) on the nuget.org, the latest version is only `2.1.0-preview1-final (current version)` not have the version `2.1.0-preview3-32169`. So the package you have installed is not comes from nuget.org.

If you add a custom nuget feed with source: https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json

Then you will see the version `2.1.0-preview3-32169`.

So, to resolve this issue, you should select the nuget.org as package source or disable the package source from dotnet.myget.org.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 49):

Thanks @LeoLiu-MSFT
In my case, I was not seeing any other option than the Microsoft Visual Studio Offline package so I need to add myself.

1. click on the setting Icon

[image]

2. Below window will open write the NuGet details if does not allow to write edit the existing

> ```
>   nuget.org
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
> ```

[image]

Comment: Worked for me. VS 2019.